# How to make entity array in inline editor of dialogflow directly?

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

We can upload CSV or JSON file for entities at Dialogflow.
But I want to make an array for entities in inline editor of Dialogflow.

For example,

```
function hello(agent) {
  //[I want to make entities array in the function with API call]
  }
```

How can make that array?  Is this correct?

```
add.entities({
  "entries": [{
      "synonyms": ["apple", "red apple"],
      "value": "apple"
    },
    {
      "value": "banana"
    }
  ],
  "name": "fruit"
})
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying that you want to change the Entities for a user for a particular session? Or be able to edit them or... what? Can you describe the full scenario for what you're trying to do, or show the full set of code of what you're trying to do that isn't working?

Comment: Thank you for responding. For example, we can put entities array by inner option of entities with csv or JSON. But I want to put this array by using inline editor not using the ways that I just sayed.  If you keep being confused, tell me please. I really want to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm still confused - you just repeated what you said in your original question. I know what the inline editor is, but its for code, so I don't know what you mean by "using inline editor". When are you expecting this code to run? Why do you want to do it this way? Have you tried something already that doesn't work? What have you tried and what happened? Can you update your question with code or examples of how you want it to work?

Comment: i think the OP wants to add entities and their synonyms through the code. like we can add add an entity or a synonym in console

Comment: Yes! Like what sid8491 said. I want it precisely. I am sorry to make you confuse because of my wrong response...

Comment: .I guess i should make more or less like this..  var city = request.body.entities[{..{..}..}]; But I don't know exactly

Comment: No need to be sorry, but I'm asking the questions I do trying to make the question clear and make sure you get an answer that helps you and others. I had a bunch of questions above - and updating the original question with those answers will help. Right now, there are a bunch of possible answers, but only one will help you, so being clear about what you need and how you plan to use it will help you get a good answer. Updating your original question to clarify it with the questions I asked will help.

Comment: I am sorry again. Before solving this question, I have to solve other solution to answer well to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53795822/how-to-make-the-correct-flow-in-dialogflow-with-webhook

Comment: So, could you recommend something other question first? Thank you so much.