# How to make the correct flow in dialogflow with webhook?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es

[image]I have some questions.
I want to make a bot with this procedure.
ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ
I : Hello 
Bot : Welcome to my agent!
Bot : What's your name?
I : Smith
Bot : Smith
Bot : 1
Bot : 2
ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ
I made intents 'hello' that has parameter as 'name' required.
But when it runs, it works with the order below.
ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ
I : Hello
Bot : What's your name?
I : Smith
Bot : Welcome to my agent!
ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ
It's totally different with my intention.
Could you recommend the correct way to make my object?
Thank you so much.

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug';

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function hello(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);

    let city = request.body.queryResult.parameters['name']; 
    agent.add(`${city}`);

    information().then((a) => {
    agent.add(JSON.stringify(a)); 
  });
}

  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
}

  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('hello', hello);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);

  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});

function information(){
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var a = ['1','2'];
    resolve(a);
         });
    }
```

Comment: Can you update your question to show the screen shots of the Intents that you have defined and that you think should be triggered at each stage? It isn't clear, for example, what is supposed to be sending the "What is your name" prompt or why you think it would happen in the order you specified.

Comment: I attached the photo about the Intents that is very simple. I want to know the order to see how it gives it. After understanding, I would construct my real example. But when I practice like that with simple example, it doesn't work following my intention. So, that is, I want bot to say that when it access to Intents, [1] Bot says 'Agent.add(hello)' [2] Bot asks my name as parameters. [3]  Bot says my name as parameters. [4] Bot says the values of array through a function that is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have set `name` as a required parameter, Dialogflow will wait to call the fulfillment webhook until all required parameter have been filled (unless you have the switch to use fulfillment for slot filling on, which you don't).

So what happens is:

- The Intent is triggered because "hello" matches the Intent
- There is a missing parameter `name`, so Dialogflow prompts for it
- The user replies and `name` is filled
- Dialogflow sends the information to your webhook
- Your code adds the "welcome" message

Here is where it gets tricky. Not all clients support multiple messages in the reply, or support that many, so the additional `add()` calls may get ignored depending which client you're testing with. In general - you should only be adding different types of responses (text, cards, etc) to be cross-platform compatible.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am resoloving little by little thank to your advice. But I have more questions.. could you help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53802663/how-to-connect-webhook-of-my-local-to-dialogflow